# What does Euc. VI mean?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

[image]

You can just tell me what does this Euc. VI mean. I tried searching Euc.VI and also Euc VI postulate. I got nothing. Please tell me what does this mean or how is AB/ab = OA /Oa ? P

Comment: Euclid's Elements, Book 6 (VI), proposition 2. https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVI/bookVI.html

Comment: @John_Krampf Thanks

Comment: Can I say that AC > BD?@John_Krampf

Comment: @user15072279 No. The polygon's $\ ABCD\dots\ $ being regular implies that $\ AC=BD=CE=\dots\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I appreciate your answer but I was asking for the link sent by John proposition 2.

Comment: How does a question about $AC$ and $BD$ relate to the link? Neither the link itself nor the linked web page contain symbols $AC$ or $BD$...

Comment: @user15072279 The cited reason for the equation $\frac{AB}{Ab}=\frac{OA}{Oa}$ is not Proposition 2, but Proposition 4. The triangles $AOB$ and $aOb$ are equiangular because $\angle AOB$ and $\angle aOb$ are the same angle and $ab$ is parallel to $AB$.  Therefore, Proposition 4 tells you that the sides opposite the corresponding angles $\angle OBA$ and $\angle Oba$ (namely, $OA$ and $Oa$) must be in the same ratio as those opposite the corresponding angles $\angle AOB$ and $\angle aOb$ (namely, $AB$ and $ab$). That is, $\frac{AB}{Ab}=\frac{OA}{Oa}$.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera thanks . Got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\triangle Oab$ and $\triangle OAB$ are both isosceles and they share the same angle $\angle AOB$; Therefore, they are similar. Hence, $\frac{AB}{ab}=\frac{OA}{Oa}$.